# Mysql slow query log is calling stored procedure and how can I view the actual select query in order to explain it

Tags: mysql, performance

I've `asp.net` application which use Mysql CPU usage up to 99%. I want to tune down the CPU usage. I checked the slow query log, and find it most are stored procedure.
I want to catch the actual select query that the mysql is running and then I can explain it and do indexing or performance tuning.

Can I view the actual select query? Or am I just asking impossible question?

Comment: Check out this url, please.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-debugger.html

Comment: I don't think the slowlog can see items in a stored routine.  Another approach is to periodically do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.  Look for frequent items and/or items with a large "Time".